# Align drawable to top-left corner in multiline edittext

Tags: android, layout, android-edittext, alignment, drawable

I have a `drawable` that I would like to align to the top-left corner in my multiline `EditText`. Here's what I have so far:

```
<EditText
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:background="@android:color/transparent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:inputType="textMultiLine|textCapSentences"
    android:ems="10"
    android:drawableLeft="@drawable/ic_email_body"
    android:gravity="top|left"
    android:textColorHint="@color/hint_text"
    android:textColor="@color/text"
    android:hint="Compose"
    android:drawablePadding="10dp"
    android:id="@+id/email_body"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/email_subject"
    android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/email_subject"
    android:layout_below="@+id/email_subject"
    android:layout_above="@+id/send_email"/>
```

This is how it looks in android studio:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/a99rL.png

The `drawable` in the `Compose` `EditText` is align in the middle of the `EditText`, I would like it to be aligned directly beside the word, like in the 'To' and 'Subject' fields.

Is there any way I can go about doing this? whether via XML or programmatically?

Comment: I would also prefer that use A ImageView align to the left and EditText align to the right to get better control overs the views,

Comment: Thank You, that worked pefectly.

Comment: Thank you also , I didn't know that we can have drawable inside EditText, learnt a new thing  :D

Comment: @KlausCode please have a look at this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33755041/place-icon-at-top-left-corner-in-multiline-edittext

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hmm, to get the same style as text views couldn't you also just put add an image view and simply align them?  It would appear exactly the same as that text view. Probably easier seeing as there isn't an obvious drawabletopleft that I know of.